# How can I solve the file association issue in my Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting

[image]

Whenever I click on this pop-up context menu, the following error message appears,

[image]

I don’t know how did it happen.

Its going on for all types.

**How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

`.ppt` is not associated with Microsoft PowerPoint. To fix this:

Control Panel > Programs > Default Programs > Associate a file type or protocol with a program

From here, find .ppt in the list of extensions, then associate it with the Microsoft Powerpoint exe. Depending on the version, usually located in "C:\Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Office\~" somewhere

Comment: its going on for all types.

Comment: Yikes, check out this post. You can download those .reg files and run them  for each filetype. The zip with all of them is at the top. http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html